# Geometrical optimization problem.

Tags: geometry, optimization

Sum of areas of 2 equilateral triangles is equal 2. Find the length of their sides for which sum of their circumferences is the smallest.

I noticed that if 3x+3y is the smallest then so is x+y and that the formula for an area of the equilateral triangle is $Area = \frac{(Side)^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$ so I constructed the Lagrangian which looks like this:

$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = x+y-\lambda(\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{y^2\sqrt{3}}{4}-2)$

and $\nabla\mathcal{L}=0$ if

$ \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{\lambda x\sqrt{3}}{2}=1\\ 
\frac{\lambda y\sqrt{3}}{2}=1\\
\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}+\frac{y^2\sqrt{3}}{4}-2=0
\end{array}
\right.$

but then the only extremum we get for x=y. What for me is quite surprising because if you can minimize the circumference you should also be able to maximize (even if one of the pair x or y is set to 0 forgetting about geometrical background of this problem) and in this case when I have one extremum only how should I know if it is maximum or minimum?

Answer (score 1):

You can state the problem also as:

Given a circle

$$ 
C \to x^2+y^2=\frac{2}{\mu}
$$

and a line

$$
L\to x + y = \lambda
$$

find the minimum/maximum values for $\lambda$ such that $C$ and $L$ are tangent but with the restrictions $x > 0$ and $y > 0$

The Lagrangian formulation then can be stated as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = x + y + \lambda_1(x^2+y^2-\frac{2}{\mu})+\lambda_2(x-\epsilon_1^2)+\lambda_3(y-\epsilon_2^2)
$$

Here $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ are slack variables to avoid the inequalities. Now the stationary points can be found by solving

$$
\nabla L = (2\lambda_1x+\lambda_2+1,2\lambda_1 y +\lambda_3+1,x^2+y^2-\frac{2}{\mu},x-\epsilon_1^2,y-\epsilon_2^2,\epsilon_1\lambda_2,\epsilon_2\lambda_3) = 0
$$

and the solution is at

$$
x = y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu}}\ \  \mbox{giving}\ \  x+y = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\mu}}
$$

Comment: yeah right. Then these tangent points are in the 1st and the 3rd quarter of the xy-plane the one in the 1st quarter is the maximum the one in the 3rd would be a minimum, but then both x and y < 0 so such a triangle could not exist. Does it mean that this function does not obtain its minimum on the open set $\big{(}0,\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}\big{)}^2$? If yes how you prove it?

Comment: What is happening? Of course two additional restrictions should be considered: $x > 0$ and $y > 0$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is not a minimum, to check let compare with the solution for $y=0$ that is

$$\frac{x^2\sqrt{3}}{4}-2=0\implies x^2=\frac 8 {\sqrt 3} \implies x=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{\sqrt[4] 3}$$

thus what you are obtaining is the maximum value for $x+y$.

Note that the minimum should be reached for $x=y=-\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]3}$ but we are excluding that solution since we also need that $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ which are two others constraints to be considered in the original problem.

Comment: alright should I say then that the minimum cannot be obtained, because we are considering $(x,y)\in\big{(}0,\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(3)^{\frac{1}{4}}}\big{)}^2$ and this is not a closed set so minimum does not have to be obtained. And in this case how do you prove that the minimum is not obtained by a function on this set?